# Unary operators "++" and "--" weird situation

Tags: javascript, unary-operator

Here's a test situation for using the unary operator "++":

```
var j = 0 ;
console.log(j);
j = j++;
console.log(j);
```

For this, the output is:

```
0
0
```

Since the ++ operator's position is at the back of the operand, so its precedence is lower than the assignment's precedence, I would expect "j" to first receive the value of itself (i.e.0), but then be incremented. So why is the second `console.log(j)` call still showing "0"?

Just to be clear, I know that the solutions are:

```
// 1)
j++;
// 2)
++j;
// 3)
j += 1;
// 4)
j = ++j;
```

But I need to know why the increment step is not conducted in this specific scenario, NOT how to fix it!

Comment: I think the ppl fast answering here do not get what you are asking and I agree with you this is confusing. I'd expect it to be 1, too.

Comment: This is why I never use the j++, ++j and all that stuff. Stick to one clear operation per line... i.e. j += 1;

Comment: No, it's precedence is much higher than the assignment? It's position doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Note that `j = j++` is behaviour undefined in C and C++, with good reason.

Comment: Postfix: passes the current value of j to j and then increments it.
Prefix: increments the current value and then passes it to j.

Comment: Precedence has nothing to do with this.

Comment: There is NEVER a reason, to use the unary operator(++) on a variable in an expression which is assigned to the same variable.

Comment: @Cruncher: Hunting for rep on SO seems like a pretty good reason!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nevermind, I thought of one. If I wanted to add `x+(x+1)+(x+2)` I could do `x = x++ + x++ + x;`. Good luck reading that. (yes I know `x*3+3` is best lol)

Comment: You are confusing *precedence* with *order of evaluation*. Remember, they have *nothing* to do with each other. When you say `d = A() + B() * C();` it is *NOT* the case that `B() * C()` is evaluated before `A()` because multiplication is higher precedence! Rather, this is the same as `a = A(); b = B(); c = C(); t = b * c; d = a + t;` The multiplication happens before the addition, but that does not change the order in which the *operands* are computed. They are computed left-to-right.

Comment: @Cruncher: Are you trying to ruin my day

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If I wanted to ruin your day I would remove whitespace. `x=x+++x+++x`. I don't even know if this is `x = x++ + x++ + x` or `x = x + ++x + ++x;` both would give the same result

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is an unintuitive (but not "weird"!) behaviour when using post-increment.

The statement `j = j++` does this:

1. *Evaluate the LHS*

   - In this case, nothing special happens because you simply named a variable, but this may not always be the case, e.g. `foo() = j++`
2. *Evaluate the RHS*

   - Take the current value of `j` (0), and remember it as the result;
   - Increment `j` (to get 1);
3. *Assign the RHS to the LHS*

   - recall that the RHS evaluates to that "remembered" value of `j` (0).

The result is a no-op.

**The key here is that the entire RHS is evaluated and the post-increment performed, *before* the final assignment.**

---

<sup>http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.3.1</sup>
<sup>http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1</sup>

Comment: The ecma-script specs (and your explanation) are confusing to me if I consider two post-increment scenarios: 1. `j=j++`; 2. `j++`. Why does j get the incremented value in the second scenario as opposed to the first, namely `j=j++`?

Comment: @AndreiOniga: `j` gets the incremented value in _both_ cases; however, in scenario #1 you are then re-assigning the original value immediately afterwards. Recall that `var j = 0; alert(j++); alert(j);` pops up `0` and then `1`, rather than `1` and then `1`.

Comment: Note that if the left hand side itself has a side effect, that side effect occurs *before* the evaluation of the right hand side.

Comment: @EricLippert: \*nods\* To be complete, I could have included an "_Evaluate the LHS_" step at the very beginning of the list of steps. I elided it in this instance, though possibly I shouldn't have. _(edit: better? :P)_

Comment: Quite fine, though I note that `foo() = whatever` is an extremely odd case, as the specification notes `the left-hand operand of an assignment is expected to produce a reference. ... function calls are permitted to return references. This possibility is admitted purely for the sake of host objects. No built-in ECMAScript function defined by this specification returns a reference and there is no provision for a user-defined function to return a reference"`. Did you have a host object in mind for `foo()` ?

Comment: @EricLippert: Not in particular. :) But I'd rather not complicate matters here by introducing another increment operation (can't think of many other relevant expressions with side-effects), so let's just let `foo()` stand for any such expression evaluating to `j`.

Comment: Note that some folks use "no-op" to describe an assembly language construct where no actual work is performed (also "NOP"). I completely agree this is _effectively_ a no-op, it's not actually a "no-op" in the assembly language sense. (Unless your compiler is super smart and optimizes.... :-)

Comment: It might be clearer to emphasize that j++ *returns* a value.  j++ returns the pre-increment value (vs. ++j which returns the post-increment value).

Comment: @Brandon: I disagree. Functions return things. `j++` is not a function. This is about evaluation.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [ECMA Specifications for Postfix Increment Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.3.1),

> 1. Let lhs be the result of evaluating LeftHandSideExpression.
> 2. Throw a SyntaxError exception if the following conditions are all true:
>
>    1. Type(lhs) is Reference is true
>    2. IsStrictReference(lhs) is true
>    3. Type(GetBase(lhs)) is Environment Record
>    4. GetReferencedName(lhs) is either "eval" or "arguments"
> 3. Let oldValue be ToNumber(GetValue(lhs)).
> 4. Let newValue be the result of adding the value 1 to oldValue, using the same rules as for the + operator (see 11.6.3).
> 5. Call PutValue(lhs, newValue).
> 6. Return oldValue.

So, it is clear that the new value is first set on the `lhs` (in this case `j`) and the the old value is returned as the result of the expression, which is again set back in `j`. So, the value doesn't change.

Comment: The relevant point is that `PutValue` (#5) is executed *before* the post-increment finishes evaluating. This is in contrast with C and C++, where the equivalent of `PutValue` is executed at the next "sequence point", and using the same operand elsewhere before the sequence point is undefined behavior and therefore forbidden.

Comment: @user4815162342: It appears that the post-increment occurs in #4, but it returns the oldValue anyways in #6 actually. Unless I misunderstood what you are saying.

Comment: @Brian: That is correct. Well, the real point is that _all of that_ occurs before the encapsulating assignment operation does its work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Right, so the take away here is to ask yourself as a programmer what is the intended behavior. My guess is here in this case the intent was actually `j += 1`.

Comment: @Brian #4 only calculates the new value, #5 stores it in `j`. Note that "LHS" here refers to the operand of the inner expression `j++`, not to the LHS of the outer assignment `j = ...`. The outer assignment receives the old value (as per #6) and resets `j` back to 0. In C, however, the post-increment operator works differently and is defined in terms of "sequence points", so in C the incrementing might be performed *after* the outer assignment. To avoid this kind of confusion, C and C++ consider "undefined" expressions that both refer to and increment the same object.

Comment: @Brian: It's impossible to tell. The intended behaviour could have been `j+=1` but then it was implemented incorrectly. If the intended behaviour was `j+=0` then it was pointless. Either way it's a construct that one should not find in real code.

Answer (score 2):

Where the ++ is lets you know what value you are going to get from it at that moment

```
++j; // increment the value and then give it to me.
j++; // give me the value and then increment it.
```

so you were saying

```
j = j++;
```

set j to the value of j before it was incremented.

Answer (score 0):

`j = j++` means assign RHS value first to LHS and then increment RHS by 1. On the other hand, `j = ++j` means increment RHS by 1 and then assign it to LHS

Answer (score -3):

j++ means at first assign,then increment

++j means at first increment,then assign

So,

```
var j = 0 ;
console.log(j);
j = ++j;
console.log(j);

0
1
```

Comment: Obviously, OP aware of this. And there are no `:=` operator in JS.

Comment: This only mistake.I recently helped my friend with Pascal:)

Comment: As J0HN pointed out, I was asking not for a solution, but for an explanation on this rather unintuitive behavior.